# CGAL Polyline Simplification results in self-intersection

Tags: c++, cgal

I'm currently having a bit of trouble with CGAL's [Polyline Simplification](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polyline_simplification_2/index.html).

More specifically, for the following example, `PS::simplify(ct, Cost(), Stop(0.2))` results in a self-intersecting polyline. In the image below, the blue polyline is the **input** polyline into `PS::simplify()` while the green polyline is the **resulting (output)** polyline. The red arrow points to the self-intersection in the resulting polyline.

Further below, I have copied and pasted my code from 2 files `simplify_test.cpp` and `CMakeLists.txt`. With the required libraries installed, to run this example, you may place them in the same directory, `cd` to that directory, and run the following in your terminal:

```
$ cmake .
$ make
$ ./simplify_test
```

This outputs the resulting coordinates (green polyline in the image below), which contain the self-intersection.

I would like to know:
**(1)** why this results in a self-intersection
and **(2)** what can be done so that it does not result in a self-intersection.

Thank you for your help!

[image: blue: input polyline, green: resulting polyline]

Here is the simplification code in a file named `simplify_test.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyline_simplification_2/simplify.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Point_2<K> Point;
typedef std::vector<Point> Polyline;
namespace PS = CGAL::Polyline_simplification_2;
typedef PS::Vertex_base_2<K> Vb;
typedef CGAL::Constrained_triangulation_face_base_2<K> Fb;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<Vb, Fb> TDS;
typedef CGAL::Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2<K, TDS, CGAL::Exact_predicates_tag> CDT;
typedef CGAL::Constrained_triangulation_plus_2<CDT> CT;
typedef PS::Stop_below_count_ratio_threshold Stop;
typedef PS::Squared_distance_cost Cost;

void print_coords(Polyline polyline) {
  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Simplified coordinates:" << std::endl << std::endl;

  // Print out the simplified coordinates
  unsigned int i = 0;
  for (Point coord : polyline) {
    std::cout << "[ ";
    std::cout << coord.x();
    std::cout << ", ";
    std::cout << coord.y();
    std::cout << " ]";
    if (i != polyline.size() - 1) std::cout << ",";
    i++;
  }
  std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
}

void simplify_test() {
  // Hard code a minimum working example where running PS::simplify results in
  // self-intersections. There are no self-intersections when {27, 9} is
  // omitted.
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> coords = {
      {64, 20}, {33, 27}, {27, 9}, {33, 18}, {44, 18}, {44, 8},
      {24, 0},  {0, 13},  {9, 49}, {84, 41}, {83, 29}, {64, 20},
  };
  // Simplification outputs:
  // [ 64, 20 ],[ 27, 9 ],[ 44, 18 ],[ 24, 0 ],
  // [ 9, 49 ],[ 83, 29 ],[ 64, 20 ],[ 64, 20 ]

  // Create polyline for simplifying later
  Polyline polyline;

  // Insert coordinates into polyline
  for (std::vector<int> coord : coords) {
    Point pt(coord[0], coord[1]);
    polyline.push_back(pt);
  }

  // Insert polyline into ct and run simplify()
  CT ct;
  ct.insert_constraint(polyline.begin(), polyline.end());
  PS::simplify(ct, Cost(), Stop(0.2));
  Polyline polyline_simplified;

  // Transfer simplified coordinates from ct to polyline for easy handling
  auto cit = ct.constraints_begin();
  for (auto vit = ct.points_in_constraint_begin(*cit);
       vit != ct.points_in_constraint_end(*cit); vit++) {
    polyline_simplified.push_back(*vit);
  }

  print_coords(polyline_simplified);
}

int main() {
  simplify_test();
}
```

Here is the `CMakeLists.txt` file.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(simplify_test LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

# Detecting appropriate compiler
if (APPLE)
  set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++")
elseif(UNIX) # implicit AND NOT APPLE
  set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "g++-10")
  set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "gcc-10")
endif()

# Finding appropriate packages
find_package(CGAL)

# Adding executables needed
add_executable(simplify_test ./simplify_test.cpp)

# Linking appropriate libraries required
target_link_libraries(
  simplify_test
  CGAL::CGAL
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I further reduced it to a polyline     `std::vector<std::vector<int> > coords = { {64, 20}, {33, 27}, {27, 9},  {33, 18}, {44, 18}, {24, 0} };`

You found a bug in the points in constraint iterator.   As a workaround you should use the [`Vertex_in_constraint_iterator`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/classCGAL_1_1Constrained__triangulation__plus__2.html#af0763d7caf0781baab11e743cac22729) and then call the method `point()`.  I will file an issue on github and a fix.

Comment: It is fixed in this pull request on [github](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/pull/5774).  Hope this is accepted as an answer, even if for me the proposed workaround  is one.

Comment: Hi Andreas, thank you for your response. After experimenting, the proposed workaround does indeed work for my purposes. I suppose these fixes on GitHub will not be available any time soon but will only be included in the next release of CGAL?

Answer (score 1):

In the C++ code below, I essentially replaced `Polyline` with `Polygon_with_holes_2`. For all values of `stop`, I now get topologically valid simplified polygons. I edited your output function. You can copy and paste the output from the new function `print_coords_for_geogebra()` directly into [Geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator).

Here is the edited version of `simplify_test.cpp`. You can compile it with the same `CMakeLists.txt` that you included in your original post.

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyline_simplification_2/simplify.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_with_holes_2.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Point_2<K> Point;
namespace PS = CGAL::Polyline_simplification_2;
typedef PS::Stop_below_count_ratio_threshold Stop;
typedef PS::Squared_distance_cost Cost;
typedef CGAL::Polygon_2<K> Polygon;
typedef CGAL::Polygon_with_holes_2<K> Polygon_with_holes;

void print_coords_for_geogebra(Polygon ext_ring)
{
  unsigned int i = 0;
  std::cout << "Polygon(";
  for (Point coord : ext_ring) {
    std::cout << "("
              << coord.x()
              << ", "
              << coord.y()
              << ")";
    if (i != ext_ring.size() - 1) std::cout << ", ";
    i++;
  }
  std::cout << ")" << std::endl << std::endl;
}

void simplify_test2(Polygon_with_holes polygon, double stop)
{
  Cost cost;
  polygon = PS::simplify(polygon, cost, Stop(stop));
  print_coords_for_geogebra(polygon.outer_boundary());
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::vector<std::vector<int> > coords = {
    {64, 20}, {33, 27}, {27, 9}, {33, 18}, {44, 18}, {44, 8},
    {24, 0},  {0, 13},  {9, 49}, {84, 41}, {83, 29}, {64, 20},
  };

  // Insert coordinates into the external ring of a polygon with holes
  Polygon ext_ring;
  for (std::vector<int> coord : coords) {
    Point pt(coord[0], coord[1]);
    ext_ring.push_back(pt);
  }
  Polygon_with_holes polygon(ext_ring);
  print_coords_for_geogebra(polygon.outer_boundary());
  for (double stop = 1.0; stop > 0.0; stop -= 0.1) {
    simplify_test2(polygon, stop);
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```